# Is this some entropy I haven't heard of?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, entropy

For a discrete finite probability distribution $p(s)$ the function $$\sum\limits_s p(s)\log ^2 p(s)$$ looks like the Shannon entropy but has a square on the $\log$. Is there a name for this? Or it is meaningless?

Comment: Where did you encounter this? Also, note that as written this is non-positive, which might not be what you intended.

Comment: @Stef I think "meaningless" in this context doesn't mean "it makes no difference" but "it doesn't map to any general concept similar to entropy".

Comment: One speculation would be that this is a typo or some nonstandard notation for "log base 2", which would be a very, very common way to measure entropy (in bits).

Comment: thanks for comments. Minus sign was a typo. I encountered this expression when deriving some results in thermodynamics. It is supposed to be a $(\log (p(s)))^2$ the 2 is not a typo

Comment: I was thinking it may be related to the fisher information / fisher metric maybe?

Answer (score 0):

This relative of Shannon's entropy fails to display additivity and is not maximized for a uniform distribution. These properties are often desirable in a measure of information and are properties of Shannon's entropy.

*For instance:*

Additivity: $H(.25,.25,.25,.25) \neq H(.5,.5) + H(.5,.5)$.

Uniform Maximum:  $H(.5,.5)\approx .48 \space \text{while} \space  H(.9,.1)\approx .54$

In fact, here is the plot of the function for two outcome R.V. Uniform is a local minimum.

[image]