# Name of a quantity related to Shannon entropy, but with squared logarithm

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, logarithms, terminology, entropy

Let $k\geq 1$. For any probability distribution $p=(p_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ over $\mathbb{N}$, let
$$
H_k(p) \stackrel{\rm def}{=} \sum_{n=1}^\infty p_n \log^k\frac{1}{p_n} \in[0,\infty]
$$
For $k=1$, $H_1(p)=H(p)$ is the (Shannon) entropy. Does $H_2(p)$ have a name? Is it a standard quantity?

Comment: Related/relevant (but not really answered): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592759/is-this-some-entropy-i-havent-heard-of?rq=1

Comment: I have been told that tthe case $k=2$ is called *"Kullback-Leibler variations"* in 

``Ghosal, Subhashis; van der Vaart, Aad. Fundamentals of nonparametric Bayesian inference. Cambridge Series in Statistical and Probabilistic Mathematics, 44. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2017. xxiv+646 pp. ISBN: 978-0-521-87826-5``

Comment: This is just  $E[ ( \log \frac{1}{p_X(X)})^k]$. If you define a notion of information density $i(X) =\log \frac{1}{p_X(X)}$. Then, it's just the $k$-the moment of information density.